# How to get base_baud frequency of a com-port in windows

Tags: windows, ioctl, baud-rate

Is there a windows call to get the baud base frequency, like this one in linux.

```
struct serial_struct ser;
ioctl(com, TIOCGSERIAL, &ser);
base = ser.baud_base;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DCB ser;
ser.DCBlength = sizeof (DCB);
if (GetCommState (com, &ser))
  base = ser.BaudRate;
```

See [Configuring a Communications Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363201(VS.85).aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

No, what I'm after is the internal clock used for generating baud rates. I want to calculate what non standard baud rates are possible to set. 
In linux it's:

```
struct serial_struct ser;
ioctl(com, TIOCGSERIAL, &ser);
base = ser.baud_base;
baudrate = ser.baud_base / ser.custom_divisor;
```